# Git extensions--why am I seeing multiple labels for the same branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-extensions

So I thought that I did a simple merge from my feature branch back down into master. However, in Git Extensions it's showing labels a couple of revisions back in a faded style (see image). What the heck is this supposed to mean? The documentation is extremely lacking. If I do a `git status` on both the master and the branch it says that there's nothing to commit and the working tree is clean.

[image: Git extensions showing duplicate tags]

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking why that 3rd commit from the top there has those washed out labels for `origin/master` and `master`, when there are also much more prominent labels for the same branches on the first commit?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Good question, can't say I've seen this. Just to stave off others trying to answer here: On the first commit we see two local branches (the first two labels) and two remote ones. Local branches are the dark colored ones and the remote ones are the green ones. So yes, the first commit tells us that we have 2 local branches, `Feature-AddThisEnhancements` and `master` which are in sync with their remote counterparts. The question is why that third commit, "Updated project references" also have two pastel labels and what those signifies.

Comment: Question, do you have the two "superproject" branch options enabled in the view menu, and is this a subrepository of a parent repository? Could it be that the parent repository thinks this subrepository should be at that commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the effect of these two settings in Git Extensions:

- View -> Show superproject branches
- View -> Show superproject remote branches

Basically, the repository you've shown the history of is a submodule of a surrounding repository. The submodule repository have two commits that the parent repository isn't aware of yet.

Let me explain.

When you commit in a repository which has a submodule, the sha of the commit the submodule repository is at is recorded in the parent repository. Thus, the parent repository thinks the submodule should be at that third commit.

However, the repository in that submodule has a life of its own, and after the parent repository was told to use that third commit, another two commits has been added to this submodule repository.

Those washed out labels signifies where the parent repository thinks the submodule should be.

Comment: Yes, this is it exactly! I was working in a submodule, so apparently just checking in my changes in the submodule was not enough. I also had to stage the changes to my submodule for the parent repo as well, and then commit. Thanks again!